# React Native fetch cache not working (cannot ENABLE caching)

Tags: javascript, react-native, caching, http-headers, fetch

There are lots of questions regarding how to *disable* cache in React Native fetch. I seem to be stuck with the *reverse* problem - I have a server side API that has correct cache headers (caching is working fine for fetch calls in Google Chrome).

```
fetch('https://mywebsite.com/endpoint/', {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  }
}).then((response) => {
   return response.json();
}).then((responseJson) => {
     console.log(responseJson);
    // Response has a timestamp, and I can verify that it is always fresh
});
```

Response headers visible in Chrome inspector:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: max-age=172800
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 2748
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Thu, 06 Dec 2018 08:55:55 GMT
Expires: Sat, 08 Dec 2018 08:55:55 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=998
Pragma: cache
Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
```

Code on server (PHP):

```
$expires = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", time() + AppConfig::mobileApiCacheTimeInSeconds) . " GMT";
header("Expires: $expires");
header("Pragma: cache");
header("Cache-Control: max-age=" . AppConfig::mobileApiCacheTimeInSeconds);
```

However, in my react native application - the API calls are never cached. I read somewhere that caching is not guaranteed - but I expected that caching should work most of the times (device has enough memory - if that controls cache purging). I am also trying on an emulator, and see that calls are always made to server (never cached).

Could it be because its a development build? Is caching disabled on emulator? I cannot find any documentation regarding this.

Comment: did you try with axios?

Comment: @HelmerBarcos  No. Wanted to avoid extra packages